# Excel VBA sort by multiple criteria by successive clicking on a cell/text

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort excel columns in a table based on clicked column header. So far, I have the code below and it works fine. I click on a header and the table is sorted by the column header that I clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("active[#Headers]")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim KeyRange As Range
        Set KeyRange = Range(Target.Address)

        SortOrder = xlAscending

        If Target.Value = "price" Then
            SortOrder = xlDescending
        End If

        If Target.Value = "profit" Then
            SortOrder = xlDescending
        End If

        Range("active").Sort Key1:=KeyRange, Header:=xlYes, Order1:=SortOrder
    End If

End Sub
```

When I click on a different header cell, previous sort is canceled and new is set. And that's what I would like to change. I would like t add secondary sort criteria, instead of changing the primary.

I would like to sort by multiple criteria, just by successive clicking on different header cells. For example first sort by price, then by due date then by something else. This combination can be different, so I can't really use vba sort criteria 1,2,3 and do the sort all in one pass.

For clearing the sort order, I use this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("active").ListObjects("active").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
```

Do you have any ideas, how to achieve this?

*Please do not ask me why I wrote the code the way it is written. I do not know. Unfortunately I'm not a coder, I roughly understand how the code works, but I do not have any deeper knowledge. I put this code together from different sources just by searching and then trying how it works (or more often how it doesn't work).*

Comment: I wouldn't worry about how your code looks because it's not too bad. Pretty interesting question, too :)

Comment: @krystof-stulc: don't worry about how the code is written, it looks fine ...

Comment: I would suggest you to "add" newly clicked column as the new sort order. Plus you will have a problem if you want to allow excel to work as usual (one column sort) and with multi sort. We use an "alt+ key" or "ctrl+ key" on those occasions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can improve your code by changing the use of `Range` in `Range("active[#Headers]")` and `Range("active").Sort` to the built-in properties and methods of a `ListObject` - [`ListObject.HeaderRowRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ListObject.HeaderRowRange) and [`ListObject.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.sort).
- `Select Case` might be neater as well, instead of multiple `If` statements.
- `Range(Target.Address)` is redundant - you can just use `Target`.
- `Add`ing a `SortField` will retain the existing sort options.

Making those changes, your code might look something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim lObj As ListObject: Set lObj = Me.ListObjects("active")
    Dim SortOrder As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, lObj.HeaderRowRange) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Price", "Profit"
                SortOrder = xlDescending
            Case Else
                SortOrder = xlAscending
        End Select

        With lObj.Sort
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Target, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=SortOrder
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may help you.  The sort details are within the `worksheet` object, so I've used the range.worksheet relationship, but you could easily declare this as the sheet rather than using this way

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim s As Sort
Dim sf As SortField

Set r = Range("a1:c7")
Set s = r.Worksheet.Sort
Set sf = s.SortFields.Add(Range("b1"), XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, XlSortOrder.xlAscending)
```

I'm not too sure how you'd go about removing specific sorts though, may have to loop them and get the key as `s.SortFields.Item(x).Delete` uses an index number for x

Comment: Not sure why you're proposing grabbing the sort details from the `Worksheet`  as opposed to the `ListObject`

Comment: No, just showing how I'd do it for a normal range sorting.  I grasped that the OP was eager to learn with help, rather than just wanting something to copy verbatim.